# Strange JWASM (MASM-compatible) behaviour

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
cmp word ptr ds:[0], 0AA55h
```

assembled and objdumped, it looks like this:

```
67 81 3d 00 00 00 00    addr32 cmpw $0xaa55,0x0
55 aa
```

Why addr32 is here? I mean to do the same thing I did in AT&T (GAS) syntax:

```
cmpw    $0xAA55, %ds:0
```

which, in its turn, objumped:

```
81 3e 00 00 55 aa       cmpw   $0xaa55,0x0
```

There is `use16` in the beginning of the file, and almost everything seems ok, except of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the reason is that actually you have specified .i386 (or higher) directive in JWASM, what results in 32-bit code generation as Intel 80386 was a 32-bit CPU.

Try compiling this code with .i286 directive in order to archive real 16-bit code.

Comment: but it is 16 code you see, it used an address size override to get a 32bit address

Comment: Probably the segment of this code has "use16"?
So the code segment is specified as a 16-bit, but a targeted architecture is 32-bit (I guess).

Comment: Ok that makes sense, hope OP comes back to confirm